# Display only formatted text from mysql database

Tags: javascript

I have an `<a>` to pull information from a mysql database field and display it into a div within a bootstrap modal. This also opens the modal.

```
echo "<td> <a href='#myModal' class='view' role='button' data-toggle='modal' data-id='".$row['id']."' data-assignment='".$row['assignment']."'>View </a> </td>";
```

The javascript to do this looks is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){

     $('a.view').click(function(){
       var id = $(this).data('id'); 
       var assignment = $(this).data('assignment'); 

       $('#id').val(id);
       $('#assignment').innerHTML(assignment);
        });

     });

</script>
```

I currently have two problems,

**1.** The innerHTML is not working, meaning nothing displays in the modal within the div. But if I switch it to `$('#assignment').val(assignment);` and change the div to a textarea in the modal it displays with the text formatting which leads me to my second problem.

**2.** The assignment field is a `blob` in the mysql database and includes html formatted text. (i.e. `<p><b>Demo</b>Text here showing the formatted <i>text</i>`) when it needs to display like:

**Demo** Text here showing the formatted *text*

So my two questions are:

How can I display the values in a div?

and

How do I make the text appear as normal?

Comment: $('#assignment').html(assignment);

Comment: Can you put this as an answer so I can accept it. Not to mention I feel like a total idiot and probably should go to bed since I didn't know this....

Comment: I did. Also see the other answer. html() and text() - text() can be used in HTML and XML whereas html() only for html documents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#assignment').html(assignment);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#assignment').innerHTML(assignment);  //wrong
```

It should be like [**.text()**](http://api.jquery.com/text/),  set the text contents of the matched elements.

```
$('#assignment').text(assignment);
```

or 
the [.html()](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/html#val) function can take strings of HTML, and will effectively modify the `.innerHTML` property.

```
$('#assignment').html(assignment);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are going to add a child element better use

```
 $('#assignment').append(assignment)
```